# Ugly bug? First item in RelativeLayout cannot be centered

Tags: android, layout

We try a simple thing. Display a TextView horizontally and vertically centered in a RelativeLayout.

This should be

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Against all expectations the text appears top left here.

But now add a totally pointless LinearLayout to the whole thing:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- First item in a relative Layout cannot be centered  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and tadaaaa! The text appears where we want him to. You cannot remove any of the lines in the LinearLayout without changing the location of the TextView. It seems RelativeLayout needs some items to be aligned against top/bottom and right/left before you can center any other item.

Comment: Why not use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` ?

Comment: Also, what SDK/ADT are you using?

Comment: The behavior is the same with centerInParent. I am using Build: v21.1.0-569685

Comment: The first code correctly displays text in both vertical and horizontal center. Tested in IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Are you actually running this code? Or are you going by the preview in Eclipse? And if you are running this code, what are you running it on?

Comment: running on Galaxy S3 and HTC Sensation with same results. The preview in Eclipse always shows the text centered and claims the LinearLayout to be useless (which it should be)

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `android:orientation="vertical"` inside your `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: I tried both 'android:orientation="vertical"' and 'android:orientation="horizontal"' as well as removing it but it does not have any effect

Answer (score 1):

## Similar problem ?

#### Problem description

I currently have a similar issue with a wrapping `RelativeLayout` holding a `TextView` that should be centered due to the use of `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

Running my code on an API level 21 device or emulator shows the text properly centered.

However running the same code on API level 19 puts the text view at the top of the wrapping RelativeLayout instead of centered.

#### Example project

Just for the ease of following I created a sample project at https://github.com/hanscappelle/SO-16731025 Just check out this code from git and import in Android Studio and you should be able to run the code.

#### Visualisation

You can even test this issue using the design preview in Android Studio by just changing the SDK version for rendering.

Just open the file at `layout/with_scrollview.xml` and you should get a visualisation of it in the preview in Android Studio.

Using API level 21:

[image]

Same layout using API level 19:

[image]

## Work around

#### Wrapping ScrollView

As a work around I discovered that removing the wrapping ScrollView solves the problem.

## What didn't help

#### Dummy view

Adding a dummy `LinearLayout` (or any other view) in between like you suggested didn't resolve my problem.

The example project has this technique applied in the circle at the right of the screen.